1st order variation of a function
Consider the function $f(x(t),t)$ where $f$ is differentiable. We would like to compute the 1st order variation $\delta f$ of $f$ with the variations $x = x^* + \delta x$ and $t = t^* + \delta t$ and the variation as:
$f(x^*(t^*+ \delta t) + \delta x, t^* + \delta t)$
My book states that the 1st order variation $\delta f$  is given by
$\delta f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \delta x + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t})\delta t$
However I thought that $\delta f$ is simply given by the total differential
$\delta f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \delta x +   \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\delta t$
Where is the extra term coming from
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x} \delta t$
coming from?

Your book misapplied the chain rule. Indeed, given that $\delta x = \dot{x}\delta t$, the contribution coming from the variable $x$ has been counted twice, once due to the direct variation of $x$ as an independent variable through $\delta x$ (hence the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\delta x$ in $\delta f$) and once due to the indirect variation of $x$ as a time-dependent variable through $\delta t$ (hence the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x}\delta t$ in $\delta f$).
This error originates in the pertubation $x = x^* + \delta x$. When $x$ is itself time-dependent, the point of expansion $x^* = x(t^*)$ doesn't change, even if it is now parametrized by $t^*$, hence $x(t) = x^* + \delta x(t)$, with $\delta x(t) = x(t^* + \delta t) - x(t^*) = \dot{x}(t^*)\delta t$, which is equivalent to $x(t) = x(t^* + \delta t)$. In consequence, the expression $x(t^* + \delta t) + \delta x$ counts the variation of $x$ twice and only one of the associated terms in $\delta f$ should be kept in the final result.
